# jQuery prevent function to duplicate on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to initiate a plugin only if clicked on its parent element (because that element is being appended with jQuery so it does not exist when page loads), So I am trying following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.wrap', function(){
    ColorPicker(

        document.getElementById('slider'),
        document.getElementById('picker'),

        function(hex, hsv, rgb) {

        });
});
```

This works fine, but every time I click on the `.wrap`, it duplicates (please check the demo to see the problem). Is there anyway to fix it?

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/rhzzG/

(Click in the box to see the problem)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `on()` to trigger this event every time the element is clicked, simply use [jQuery's `one()` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to only fire it once:

```
$(document).one('click', '.wrap', function(){ ... });
```

ColorPicker will then take over from there with handling its own events.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rhzzG/1/).

Answer (score 2):

You may use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead

```
$(document).one('click', '.wrap', function(){
    //...
});
```